# Bookmarklet to add text to first subpath

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a bookmarklet which inserts text after the main domain but before any subpath e.g.

http://example.com/home/start -> http://example.com/text/home/start

I was thinking I would store the full path, edit out the domain, replace that with a regEx pattern to add the text and then document.location.replace to the new URL.

Is this too involved and a dumb way of attempting this?

Comment: Doesn't sound too involved at all, sounds like the bare essentials necessary to achieve the goal, which is just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location` have already parse these for you, so it's simply

```
`${location.origin}/text${location.pathname}`
```